# html/css review slider works on codepen, but not on actual website

Tags: magento2

I built out a review slider to display various reviews from customers across all of our marketplaces, it works great on codepen, but not so much on the website. Im sure im missing something simple, but can't figure it out.

Platform: Magento 2.3.5 P2

[How the slider appears on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFSzL.png)

https://codepen.io/hqqh/pen/VwpzGYV

```css
  

.slider {

            background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(235, 235, 235, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(235, 235, 235, 1) 100%);
            box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
            height: 250px;
            margin: auto;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            width: 1280px;
            padding-top: 30px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        .slider::before,
        .slider::after {
            background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%);
            content: "";
            height: 290px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 200px;
            z-index: 2;

        }

        .slider::before {
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

        .slider::after {
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            transform: rotateZ(180deg);
        }

        @keyframes scroll {
            0% {
                transform: translateX(0);
            }

            100% {
                transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 7))
            }

        }

        .slide-track {
            animation: scroll 60s linear infinite;
            display: flex;
            width: calc(250px * 14);
        }

        .slide {
            height: 214px;
            width: 350px;

        }

        .review-card {
            background: white;
            margin: 10px;
            height: 195px;
            padding: 7px;
            box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
            border-radius: 10px;


        }

        .review-card-header {
            height: 80px;
        }

        .review-card p {
            font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
        }

        .ebay-logo,
        .az-logo {
            position: relative;
            top: -40px;
            left: -40px;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
        }

        .review-content {
            padding: 5px;
            height: 60px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            bottom: 18px;
        }

        .review-content::before,
        .review-content::after {
            font-family: FontAwesome;
            padding: 5px;
            color: #d3d3d3;
            margin: 5px;

        }

        .review-content::before {
            content: "\f10d";
        }

        .review-content::after {
            content: "\f10e";
        }
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <h2 style="text-align: center; font-size: 42px; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: oswald;">Over
                    1,000,000 Happy Customers Served</h2>
                <h4 style="text-align: center; font-family: Roboto;">These are just a handful of the reviews we have
                    received recently across all of our marketplaces </h4>
                <div class="slider">

                    <div class="slide-track">
                        <div class="slide ">

                            <div class="review-card">
                                <div class="col-lg-3 review-card-header">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <img class="ebay-logo"
                                                src="https://integrationmaverick.net/offsite-images/eb-logo.png" border="0">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3 review-card-body">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <p class="review-content">Arrived quicker than expected, was very very well
                                                packaged, paint was excellent. Would highly recommend. Thank You</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <p style="float: right; margin-top: 0px; color: #c3c3c3">-eBay Customer 2021</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="slide ">

                            <div class="review-card">
                                <div class="col-lg-3 review-card-header">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <img class="az-logo"
                                                src="https://integrationmaverick.net/offsite-images/az-logo.png" border="0">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3 review-card-body">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <p class="review-content">Couldn’t be happier with the new front bumper cover!!! MBI auto got the paint matched perfectly, and the fit was FANTASTIC! We are thrilled! Last picture is the original bumper cover after my wreck</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <p style="float: right; margin-top: 0px; color: #c3c3c3">-Amazon Customer 2021</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>


                        <div class="slide ">

                            <div class="review-card">
                                <div class="col-lg-3 review-card-header">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <img class="az-logo"
                                                src="https://integrationmaverick.net/offsite-images/google-logo.png" border="0">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3 review-card-body">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <p class="review-content">I received the bumper I ordered sooner than expected and was pleasantly surprised. It fit just right and paint matched perfectly. I would definitely recommend trying them out for a replacement bumper.</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <p style="float: right; margin-top: 0px; color: #c3c3c3">-Google Review 2021</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>


                        <div class="slide ">

                            <div class="review-card">
                                <div class="col-lg-3 review-card-header">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <img class="az-logo"
                                                src="https://integrationmaverick.net/offsite-images/eb-logo.png" border="0">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3 review-card-body">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <p class="review-content">Arrived quicker than expected, was very very well
                                                packaged, paint was excellent. Would highly recommend. Thank You</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <p style="float: right; margin-top: 0px; color: #c3c3c3">-eBay Customer 2021</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>


                        <div class="slide ">

                            <div class="review-card">
                                <div class="col-lg-3 review-card-header">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <img class="az-logo"
                                                src="https://integrationmaverick.net/offsite-images/az-logo.png" border="0">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3 review-card-body">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <p class="review-content">Arrived quicker than expected, was very very well
                                                packaged, paint was excellent. Would highly recommend. Thank You</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <p style="float: right; margin-top: 0px; color: #c3c3c3">-Amazon Customer 2021</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>



                    </div>
                    
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row" style="text-align:center;">
                                    <p><a href="/customer-reviews" style="text-decoration: none; color: #a3a3a3; font-size: 10px; font-family: roboto">Click Here To View More Customer Reviews</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Where in magento are you inserting this code? Are you using this code inside a CMS page or something? There must be different css added by Magento?

Comment: So, i first tried to add it as a standalone block, and then adding that block to a blank CMS page. 

After that, i tried just adding it to a CMS page and still get the same effect. My first thought was something on Magento has the same class as something in my code, but i have yet to locate it. I may change the class names and see if that helps

EDIT: Did not seem to make a difference

Comment: Try to use your inspector of browser (inspect element) and see what css properties are set to cause this. Then change that css rule by overriding it. It appears someting is making the text stay in 1 line, so with your inspector click on that part of the page and see what CSS is causing this.